# libc6 partially installed on ubuntu and I am stuck

Tags: ubuntu, apt, libc

I have seen the various standard cures and none of them work. Basic problem:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-bamf-3 libbamf3-2 libgnome-menu-3-0 libplank-common libxcb-ewmh2
  libxcb-xrm0 rofi vala-panel-appmenu-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  locales
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  locales
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 84 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/6,445 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 package libc6:amd64 cannot be configured because libc6:i386 is not ready (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I very much need to fix this as I am currently hosed for installing anything or doing an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

This http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/ which advises editing dpkg status file followed by "sudo apt --fix-broken install" resolved this in my case. Pretty scary looking stuff but if it works..

Comment: Link rot!  Put the info here, please....